# Delegate on more than one event in a table created dynamically with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, delegates

First of all, I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but I've been looking for several days and I can't find a solution.

The fact is that I have two different tables (with different id's) in my page that are created dynamically (with PHP and retrieved information from phpMyAdmin). The last  of every row in table one, includes 6 (2 hidden) different buttons (a elements) to handle different events. Those events are triggered by jQuery functions contained in my file **edit_user.js**

One of those events, erases the row from where the element was clicked, and adds the information into the second table as a new row.

As well as in table1, the last  of table2 includes 2 different buttons (a elements too) with different functionalities. One of these features does the exact opposite of the functionality commented before : Returns the row in question to Table1.

Everything works fine, except for those newly inserted rows, because the a elements don't do anything.

I read about delegation and changed the way my file listens to those clicks, but I still can't get it to work:

```
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                // Set handlers for myTable
                $('table#myTable td').on('click','a.userErase',erase)
                .on('click','a.userEditable',edit)
                .on('click','a.userSuspend',suspend); 

                // Set handlers for suspTable
                $('table#suspTable td ').on('click','a.userErase',erase)
                .on('click','a.userResume',resume);
            });
```

My problem is basically with two functions, **resume** and **suspend**, because those are the one that create new rows in the tables, but I suppose that they are not delegating because new rows call different functions:

Table1
[image: table1 image]

Table2
[image: Table2 image]

For better understanding, I have the following functions in each table:

Table1

1. edit
2. change password
3. suspend
4. erase
5. accept_edit (only visible when edit is selected)
6. cancel_edit (only visible when edit is selected)

Table2

1. resume
2. erase

I generate the new rows with a code like this (it is working good but the handler not get to the event):

```
    // create a row with the info to add in suspendedTable
    var html = "<tr data-row-no=" + nextIndex + " height=\"35\"><td><div    contentEditable=\"false\" style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%;\">"+ pName 
                            + "</div></td><td><div contentEditable=\"false\" style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%;\"> "+ pSurname 
                            + "</div></td><td><div contentEditable=\"false\" style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%;\"> "+ pEmail 
                            + "</div></td><td><div contentEditable=\"false\" style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%;\"> "+ pUsername 
                            + "</div></td><td align=\"center\"> <a class=\"userResume\" id=\"resume-"+user_id + "\" href=\"#\" title=\"Activar l'usuari\">"
                            + "<i class=\"fa fa-smile-o\"></i></a></td><td align=\"center\"> <a class=\"userErase\" id=\"erase-"+user_id + "\" href=\"#\" "
                            + "title=\"Eliminar l'usuari\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></a></td></tr>\n"

                $('#suspTable tr:last').after(html);
```

The functionality is ok, if I refresh the page everything works fine, but until that moment, I can't get those new lines to work properly.

Is there a way to call for the function directly from those newly generated lines (like onClick in JavaScript)? (I tried that but neither did not function).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply delegated your events too deep. Add the handler on the `table` and not on the `td`:

```
$('table#myTable').on('click','a.userErase',erase)...
```

Because `#myTable` stays on the page and the event is bound to it it will catch clicks inside it, for newly created rows too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still is not working 100%. With your recommendation the erase functionality is working fine in rows created in both tables, but  not the other functions. I thought that I must  delegate the same events in both tables to get the other events working, but still is not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: Without seeing the code of your functions I cannot help you more. It would be good if you created a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with some of your code to show me the errors.

Comment: Your answer was right, my problem with the other methods was that my second table had less information than first one, so when I try to restore an user, I got an error so the function ended with no warning. Thank you very much for your help!